# Can't install TensorFlow 2.7.0 on an A10 GPU

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04, alibaba-cloud, tensorflow2

I am currently using the Nvidia [A10 GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Tesla#Specifications) on Alibaba Cloud.

The environment is

- [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) 64 bit
- [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) 11.4.1
- Python 3.7

I want to install TensorFlow 2.7.0 and it works well in other GPUs, but why not?

Command line:

```
pip3 install tensorflow==2.7.0
```

The error appears as:

```
Collecting tensorflow==2.7.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.7.0 (from versions: 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade --ignore-installed pip setuptools
```